# Disable autofocus of EditText at Activity startup

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, hide, android-softkeyboard

When i open my Activity my EditText automatically gain focus and it shows keyboard... So how to hide the keyboar..??

**Answer :**

**For Activity**
place the below code into your `onCreate()` method

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

**For Fragment**
place the below code into your `onCreateView()` method

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer :**

**For Activity:**
 place the below code into your onCreate() method

this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

**For Fragment:**
 place the below code into your onCreateView() method

getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);